# Нормальный отладчик под Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, отладка, gdb

Подскажите, плиз, нормальный отладчик под **Ubuntu**.

Под нормальным я подразумеваю не консольный типа **gdb** и не "поделку" вроде **ddd**. А что-то похожее на **x96dbg**, **OllyDbg** и т.п. С *нормальным* графическим интерфейсом. Чтобы было видно ассемблерный код (и не по 3 строчки, а весь, чтобы его листать можно было). Чтобы было видно регистры (*постоянно!*). Чтобы не появлялось периодически надписей вроде "GDB is busy, waiting" (из-за которой отладчик DDD виснет просто и не работает даже после перезапуска). Неужели нет **нормального** отладчика в Linux'е???

Не хочу никого обидеть, возможно вы привыкли к нему и вам он *даже* удобен. Но я в Linux совсем новичок (и оставаться там не собираюсь), захожу по чуть-чуть только 3-й день и мне кажется в нём **ВСЁ** нереальной жестью по сравнению с Windows...

***upd:*** Вот я сейчас перезагрузил систему. Запустил **ddd MyProg** и он уже несколько минут показывает "Opening session". Показывает часы вместо курсора. Ввожу команды (**break _start**, **stepi**) - ноль эмоций. Как вообще можно **ЭТИМ** пользоваться??? У меня уже нервов не хватает с этим Ebuntu разбираться!

Comment: Попробуйте *Qt Creator* (IDE такая, в том числе и под Linux). Его отладчик (мощная графическая обёртка над *gdb*) позволяет всё перечисленное вами. Также он позволяет подключаться к уже запущенному процессу. А его интерфейс ближе к Visual Studio, чем к IDA.

Comment: Вот это: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source ? А как его установить? Скачал файл с расширением .run, запускаю. Он загрузил разных прог с интернета и распаковался во множество файлов с расширением **par2**. Что теперь с ними делать?

Comment: Устанавливать надо через менеджер пакетов. Тут виндовый подход прокатывает очень редко.

Comment: Есть простенький, но вполне годный nemiver (в минте и дебиане из пакетов). Основной у меня - тот, что в Eclipse CDT, но и в других IDE/редакторах их навалом, не говоря уж о примочках ко всяким vim...

Comment: Научитесь что ли в командной строке работать. gdb уж очень мощный отладчик.

Comment: Gdb мощьный отладчик. Для него есть несколько графических оболочек xxdb , cgdb , kdbg, ddd

Comment: **don Rumata**, через менеджер пакетов - это как? Вот запустил я "менеджер приложений", ввёл "Qt Creator", ничего не нашлось.

Comment: @0andriy, я уверен, что он мощный, просто зачем извращаться, когда можно найти нормальную оболочку и через неё работать? Давайте уж тогда в машинных кодах писать, побайтово! Мощь! :))

Comment: @PinkTux, установил **nemiver**, запустил с именем программы в параметре. Открылся пустой белый экран, в котором ничего не работает. Что за прикол? Или он только Сишные проги отлаживает...? У меня чистый асм... И в консоли куча сообщений вида: *(nemiver:18718): Gtk-WARNING \*\*: Allocating size to GtkDrawingArea 0x561d9c6645a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?*

Comment: JinX, к пользователю надо обращаться через собачку: @donRumata, иначе ему уведомление не придёт.

Comment: 1) всё ловится, попробуйте попереключать окна/вид:  http://xxo.su/resizer/i/a/e/cb494d.png 2) SASM IDE

Comment: @donRumata, через менеджер пакетов - это как? Вот запустил я "менеджер приложений", ввёл "Qt Creator", ничего не нашлось.

Comment: @Arhad, у него имя с пробелом, не знал как сделать :))

Comment: @PinkTux, как переключить окна/вид? У меня вот так выглядит всё: http://i7.5cm.ru/i/EeTt.png

Comment: @Yaroslav, **ddd** у меня замирает с надписью "waiting until GDB gets ready", **cgdb** не особо отличается от gdb, **kdb** более или менее, но там нельзя менять регистры и нет перехода через команду (т.е. прыжка через *call* - всегда заходит внутрь, что F8 ("шаг внутрь"), что F10 ("шаг через")), в **xxdb** пока не понял как скачать вообще...

Comment: @JinX, `sudo apt -y install qtcreator` попробуй.

Comment: @JinX, непонятно, куда делось верхнее меню? Ну или вот это попробовать: http://dman95.github.io/SASM/

Comment: Всё, что ты просишь, умеет этот отладчик:
https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger

Answer (score 1):

Кроссплатформенный дебагер EDB с графическим интерфейсом.Вот, собственно, интерфейс:
[image: edb-debugger]
https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger
Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian...
Пользуюсь под Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Вы зря так ополчились на GDB, у него есть различные режимы отображения, а весь спектр возможностей (уж точно не быстроту их использования), GUI обертка вам, я уверен, не предоставит.

Если вам нужен режим отлаживания программы вместе с сурсами, то используйте
`layout next` или нажатием `ctrl+a`

Если вам нужен режим ассемблерного листинга, то используйте `layout asm`

[Ну посмотрите как красиво!](http://peeterjoot.com/2016/06/09/gdb-tui-mode-debugging/)

Правда есть один минус (по крайней мере в версии, которая стоит у меня и не является последней) -- в этих режимах не работают стрелочки, так как они используются для прокручивания листинга.

Чтобы это преодолеть, используйте

- `Ctrl+f` чтобы перевести курсор на 1 символ вперед
- `Ctrl+b` чтобы перевести курсор на 1 символ назад
- `Ctrl+a` чтобы перевести курсор на начало строки
- `Ctrl+e` чтобы перевести курсор на конец строки
- `Ctrl+d` то же, что и Delete
- `Ctrl+h` то же, что и Backspace

[Список](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/) всех горячих клавиш, вместе с их назначением, воспринимаемых башем

Я понимаю, что вы просили ответ **не** про GDB , но мне кажется, что вы просто его недооценили.

P.S Если вы будете использовать только клавиатуру, то ваша продуктивность возрастет. Я не найду сейчас ссылок на исследования, но среднему человеку нужно около 0.8 секунды чтобы перенести руку с клавиатуры на мышку. Еще столько же, чтобы сделать то, что он запланировал. Экономьте время :^)